# Qt on Mac - When the main window is hidden the app stop responding to the actions from the dock menu icon's context menu

Tags: c++, qt, macos

I am preparing my application for a Mac release. All is well except that when my main window is hidden (not minimized, hidden) the actions at the dock menu icon's context menu stop having any effect on my app.

The same context menu applied to a system tray icon has the desired effect. Is this a bug on Qt's Mac integration? Any workarounds?

Comment: Which actions in the dock icon's menu stop having an effect?  All of them?  (i.e. does even Quit not do anything?)  Also, which version of Qt are you using?  4.7.1?  Cocoa or Carbon?

Comment: Quit is the only one that still has the desired effect. All of the custom actions stop working when the window is hidden and clicking the icon does not reactivate the window. I'm using Qt 4.7.1